# obtaining the certificate root from another app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

if you run `codesign -d -r- myapp.app` you'll get information about the code signature. A piece of the information displayed is the certificate root, something like `certificate root = H"14bbf142a9bcc11abd868458e4ab6419ae8c170c"`

Is there any function that can return that information given the path to an app? I've checked Apple's [Code Signing Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html) but I couldn't find anything.

I am using `SecRequirementCreateWithString` and `SecStaticCodeCheckValidity` to check the certificate from within my own app but I need to also check the rest of the binaries that form the entire app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there are no available public APIs for managing Code Signing. You have to parse the output of the `codesign` tool.

Comment: How about something like: `SecCodeCopySigningInformation(staticCode, kSecCSSigningInformation, &information);`

Comment: Ah, seems like it might just do that. Sorry, I last looked into this when Code Signing was introduced in 10.5 and it looks like they added this API in 10.6.

Comment: @MrAleph You can always calculate hash by yourself. If you have data needed just SHA it.